# CodeIgniter can't send email on VPS

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm currently working on a REST API using CodeIgniter. And I got an email verification system using the gmail smtp working just fine on localhost. But when I uploaded it to the VPS server it doesn't work.

**Here's my code:**

```
protected function send_confirmation($email, $hash){
    $config = array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'xxx@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',
        'mailtype'  => 'html',
        'charset'   => 'utf-8',
        'crlf' => "\r\n",
        'newline' => "\r\n"
    );

    $this->load->library('email', $config);

    $mail = $this->email;

    $mail->from('no-reply@example.com', 'Example.com');
    $mail->to($email);

    $mail->subject('Email Verification');

    $encodemail = urlencode($email);
    $message = 'Some messages here.';

    $mail->message($message);   

    $mail->send();
}
```

Also note that I'm using **PHP 7.2**, and I've tried many configurations but nothing seems to work on the VPS server.

Comment: I think your smtp_host for google is smtp.gmail.com, try removing the ssl://

Comment: if you google gmail smtp you get [this](https://www.lifewire.com/what-are-the-gmail-smtp-settings-1170854)

Comment: pls always response to the answers by giving some comments or ,if it helps you, by marking it as green and upvoting, it is the best way to thanks all the programmers

Comment: This problem was already fixed a while after I posted this question. Turns out, it has something to do with the email that we were using, but I couldn't remember what it was. Sorry for abandoning this question for so long.

Answer (score 0):

try these

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'smtp.gmail.com', #changed
    'smtp_port' => 587, #changed 
    'smtp_user' => 'xxx@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',
    'mailtype'  => 'html',
    'charset'   => 'utf-8',
    'newline' => "\r\n"
);
```

or use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)